# ¿Cómo detectar cierre de sesión de Windows con Python?

Tags: python

Quisiera saber de que manera puedo detectar cunado se cierra la sesión de Windows utilizando Python.

Mi idea es interrumpir un flujo de mi aplicación, si se detecta un cierre de sesión en Windows. El hecho de poder detectar el inminente cierre me permitiría realizar un salto en el programa a otra parte de mi interés, así quedaría preparado para el siguiente inicio de sesión y se continuaría ejecutando desde ese punto.

Comment: En Python existe lo que se conoce como "exit handler", revisa esto: https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html

Comment: De posible interés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411186/python-windows-shutdown-events

Comment: La librería ctypers en python detecta eventos en window,un función para detectar el cierre de sesión ```
import ctypes def session_logout(): return bool(ctypes.windll.user32.WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId())

Answer (score 0):

Nunca he oído nada parecido, pero, si me permites la sugerencia; puedes hacerlo de otro modo:

En todos los ordenadores windows hay una carpeta donde, se ponga lo que se ponga, se ejecuta al iniciar sesión. Este es el directorio:`C:\Users\Tu_nombre_de_usuario\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Puedes dejar aquí otro ejecutable, que modifique los datos de un documento de texto, .env o .json del directorio donde tienes el programa principal, y que tu programa modifique su configuración en función de eso.

Sí, es una aproximación algo desviada de tu pregunta, y todo no ser nadie para corregir los códigos de otro; si me permites, cambiar algo del programa mientras se apaga windows, puede resultar en que el proceso se interrumpa, causando en inevitables bugs. Además, cuando el ordenador se autobloquea por falta de bateria, es mucho más súbito que cuando lo apagas tú, y sin embargo el programa puede leerlo como una misma cosa. Ese poco tiempo puede ser letal, al poder interrumpir tu proceso.

Answer (score 0):

La función SetConsoleCtrlHandler te permite registrar una función que se ejecutará cuando se reciba una señal de control en la consola. Las señales de control disponibles son:

```
CTRL_C_EVENT: se recibe una señal CTRL+C. Esta señal se genera cuando el usuario presiona las teclas CTRL+C en el teclado.
CTRL_BREAK_EVENT: se recibe una señal CTRL+BREAK. Esta señal se genera cuando el usuario presiona las teclas CTRL+BREAK en el teclado.
CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT: se recibe una señal CTRL+CLOSE. Esta señal se genera cuando el usuario cierra la ventana de la consola.
CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT: se recibe una señal CTRL+LOGOFF. Esta señal se genera cuando el usuario cierra sesión.
CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT: se recibe una señal CTRL+SHUTDOWN. Esta señal se genera cuando el usuario inicia un apagado.
```

Puedes utilizar el argumento ctrl_type en la función registrada para determinar qué señal de control se recibió y tomar la acción apropiada. Por ejemplo, puedes utilizar el siguiente código para registrar una función que se ejecutará cuando se reciba una señal de cierre de sesión:

```
import win32api

def my_handler(ctrl_type):
    if ctrl_type == win32api.CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
        # Código a ejecutar cuando se recibe una señal de cierre de sesión
        pass

# Registramos nuestra función como manejador de señales de control
win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(my_handler, True)
```